Single browser experience on iOS
I cannot bring myself over the way browsers work on my iPhone. The "interim" browser in apps like Gmail (when you click a link in your mail) or using the Google search app and opening a result, or when paying something online and being redirected from a banking app - it all ends up in this browser that knows no context, has no credetials saved to use and is absolutely useless. Is there a way to get rid of this? I have chrome set as the default browser is there a setting that can use it for everything?



There might be a setting in the original app (Gmail/Google Search app) which allows to either open the in-app browser or the default browser.

Also, ALL web browsing displays use Apple's (Safari) Webkit on non-Mac platforms. That Chrome browser you use on iOS? It's Apple (Safari) Webkit. Same as any other browser. That said the system keychain and Webkit should keep track of all context as it has always done on my iPhone. Perhaps there is something else going on. If you could expand on the details, that might be helpful. Of course this excepts iOS devices in the EU.

They are WKWebViews. They are seperate from your browser sessions. You can click the right bottom safari icon to open current link in safari/default browser.
